# Why Am I getting two values while indexing Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here are my data and index value image :
[image]

As in the snap pandas Dataframe returning two values. What could be possibly wrong? I am beginner, sorry for the bad editing.

Comment: What is the result of `df.index.duplicated.sum()`. If it is `> 0` then you have duplicated index values, probably result of concatenating

Comment: Yes, It is > 0. As earlier I have contacted train and test data.

Comment: When doing concat, use `ignore_index=True`. So `pd.concat([..], ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue.

```
 data['Title'].iloc[0]
```

Try something like this. I think the `.head()` portion of the code is causinng you issues